# Bug: It seems notifications on comments are broken in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, notifications

Probably since February 18th or so...

In the past if I commented on a question and a user commented back I would see a notification in my history. This is no longer the case.

Check out this question:
[Fingerprint crash on Android 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71303967/fingerprint-crash-on-android-11/71347105)

Notice that the discussion is from March... Yet this is my inbox. Notice there's nothing there after February 18th.

[image: Inbox]

Notice I didn't get any notifications for all the comments, I didn't get any emails either. This is a big problem since people incorrectly assume I see their comments.

Comment: They did not @-notify you, so it didn't notify you...

Comment: This used to work the moment I would comment on a thread you'd get a notification automatically. Without the @

Comment: You can only be notified of new comments without the @ if you are the only other person that has commented there (on that question, you're not). Or if you followed the post manually.

Comment: @animuson Weird. As a workaround can I follow the question?

Comment: Yes, following will notify you of all activity, including new comments.